# APEX 5.1.4: Creating autocomplete text fields in editable grids

Tags: autocomplete, grid, oracle-apex

I made a good experience with autocomplete text fields as far as they were created as page items. Now I try to define an edGrid column as autocomplete, but it does not "autocomplete", at all. Underlying SQL same as page item auto. I found a bug #25451910 about it, but Oracle says it's solved, now.

Does anybody know some details?

Comment: Hi, check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to ensure you will receive more attention.

Comment: Don't use the Salesforce `apex` tag for `oracle-apex` questions.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by myself. "Lazy Loading" set to "YES" made it work. Thank you.